# Check if Minimum interval between time is 2 hours with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, ajaxform

Im using the car rental plugin and need to modify it in a way that if the rental time chosen by customer is less than 2 hours, to give him a message, pop up or any kind of message, that he needs to choose time minimum 2 hours for rental.

You can see the example here: http://envato.bestsoftinc.net/wp-car/

I need to make sure that there is at least 2 hour difference between pick up date field and drop off date field, if not, I need to show him message and not let him click on the Search Button. Any ideas how I can achieve that with jQuery or Regular Javascript please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the basic logic for it, try implement this with your site. 
i found moment.js is really helpful with js time date obj you can give it a try

```
if($('#checkInDate').value() === $('#checkOutDate').value) [
```

if both date is the same date, than

```
       var checkInTime = $('#checkInTime').value(); 
       var checkOutTime = $('#checkInTime').valeu();
```

get time value

```
       if(checkOutTime > checkInTime) {
```

checkOutTime must be later than checkInTime when it's the same date

```
           if(checkOutTime - checkInTime > 2) {
```

if duration is more than 2 than this value is ok

```
               alert('ok');
```

this fail 3rd if statement

```
           } else { alert('error must less than 2 ');  }
```

this fail 2nd if statement

```
       } else {alert('error checkout must bigger than checkin'); }
```

end 1st if statement that check for same date

```
}
```

Comment: hi @wlin thanks for quick response. Im not sure this does what I need to. Im not trying to make sure that checkouttime > checkInTime. 

because if user tries to book a car at 2pm today and wants to return at 1pm tomorrow, then it would be a problem. What I need to do is make sure that user is not trying to rent a car for time duration less than 2 hours.

Comment: the 1st line, make sure if it is the same date.

Comment: uh I see. Im gonna check the code. Do I need to include the moment.js script on website or the script that you gave me is good enough? 

Thanks again @wlin :)) 

I'll post here the results : ))

Comment: This not something that you can just copy and paste.  Moment will make it easier to covert input string to date obj.  And easier to compare two date. Highly recommended. If you are not using moment. You need to pick apart your input string value and covert to native js date time obj.